# Where to store application ID and client secret for an Azure application?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powerbi-embedded

I am currently learning about Power BI embed application, and I just recently created a service principle that is able to embed Power BI reports to my test front end.

Right now I am storing all the information, including application ID and client secret in the **app.config** file, and I am accessing them in my code by using ***ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["(key)"]***.

As I read online that I should not put them in plain sight or have them hardcoded, I was wondering where could I store the application ID and the client secret, and how can I access them from my code.

I have tried storing them in the database that my service principle is connected to, which also stores all the workspace Ids and report Ids, but it is not really efficient.

I am currently using .Net 6 for my service principal for the backend and Vue for the frontend.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-servicec-principal-certificate

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Key Vault, follow this link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/storing-and-using-secrets-in-azure/ you can learn more about azure key vaults [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview)